# SharePoint Designer 2010 - Moving a list workflow to a new list

Tags: workflow, reusable

I have a three part question:

1) I'd like to reattach my large sequential list workflow to another list. I've tried the following:

- replacing a new list workflow's XML with that of my already completed workflow's XML
- playing around with wfconfig.xoml file (changing the list ID to fit that new list)

These did not work and produced a workflow error: 
"Errors were found when compiling the workflow. The workflow files were saved but cannot be run."
Advanced: "Unexpected error on server associating the workflow"

2) The workflow has repeating sections. Instead of wasting my time manually adding each section, is there a way to copy and paste a block, and then manually associate each action to a form field?

3) Is there an "Or" operator? I'd like an action to occur if one of two things is true...

For example:

```
E-mail x,
     Then pause for 2 days, OR wait until form field is changed
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Assuming you are still into development, I would suggest you develop "Re-usable Workflows". These are attached to Content Types. This way you can attach your content type to any list and your voila all works without any changes!!
2. For the Or, you should be able to use a simple if..else with conditional operators evaluating your branches.